# Where to find log messages in tomcat7 installed on Amazon EC2?

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have installed `Tomcat 7` on an `Amazon EC2` running Amazon Linux. I have installed a `WAR` file on tomcat and I am using `java.util.logging` for logging messages in my code. Now how to access those log messages in Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard location for Tomcat log files is:

```
/var/log/tomcat
```

Comment: There is folder tomcat7 at the location you suggested but I cannot `cd` into it. How do I access log file?

Comment: Try to su as root user first: `su -`, or use sudo before your commands, e.g.: `sudo ls -al /var/log/tomcat7` to see the directory content.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If I may ask which file will have `Log.log()` from my Servlets.

Comment: I would look in `catalina.out` first or one of the files starting with `localhost`. If you still don't find it, you can sort the files by date using `ls -ltr` to see the ones recently modified.

Comment: I have asked a related question here http://superuser.com/questions/444572/how-can-i-copy-my-tomcat-catalina-out-files-from-amazon-ec2-to-my-local-machine

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. In my case the application logs localhost.2019-07-19.log.For doing su - I had to create root user(using command: sudo adduser <myUserName>) for EC2 as I did not had one and helped me to access files that had permission denied prompt