# How can I copy my Tomcat Catalina.out files from Amazon EC2 to my local machine?

Tags: file-transfer, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I want to copy my `Catalina.out` from my Amazon EC2 instance to my local machine. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer it using an SCP client. There are SCP clients for most OSes, just Google around.

Comment: I have found WinSCP438 for Windows 7. Cannot I do it with the SSH session in progess. I don't want to enter my login and pwd in an unknown software.

Comment: I'm not sure about WinSCP since I don't use it (I'm on Linux), but some SCP clients also have an SSH terminal mode, allowing you to do both SCP and SSH from the same session.

Comment: WinSCP is not "an unknown software." Sure you can, in your current ssh... Just copy it to your own ftp/smb/afp/etc. server. :)

Comment: @Radoo Thanks. I have asked a related question here http://superuser.com/questions/444619/unable-to-access-tomcat7-folder-in-amazon-ec2-via-winscp-in-windows-7

Comment: @DavidLevesque AWS is not any normal OS, lots of nuances. The OP question was specific to AWS EC2 instance. By default the usual /var/log/tomcat/ user is Owned from a Linux perspective as the 'tomcat' user on Amazon Linux 2 AMI (at present, granted was not around when the OP asked the question) - Which means it's not straight forward to access. - Similar to Amazon Linux (aka. V1), things are never as straight forward as they should be by using a standard SSH / SCP client. The joys of "the cloud".