# Unable to access Tomcat7 folder in Amazon EC2 via WinSCP in Windows 7

Tags: permissions, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, winscp

I am trying to copy a file `Catalina.out` from Amazon EC2 to local machine using `WinSCP`. I have been able to establish the connection but when I try to access the tomcat7 folder I get the error

```
Permission denied. 
Error code: 3 Error message from server: Permission
denied Request code: 11
```

My question is how to access the folder tomcat7 and copy file catalina.out from it to my local machine running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your permission to catalina.out, not a problem with WinSCP. You shouldn't be able to view/read the file even in ssh console, for that matter.

I guess that, if you have admin rights, you could add rights to that file, from the console, with the chmod, or by copying the file as an admin to another location on the disk, for example in your user folder, then taking ownership of that copy using chown.

Comment: I can read the file using SSH. I am doing this in Amazon EC2. They dont have these things at console. Can you suggest some way to do it?

Comment: Are you connecting using SCP or SFTP protocol? With FTP, there's another set of privileges on top. Or perhaps you don't have list privileges to Tomcat7 folder, try getting directly to the logs folder.  You could try getting admin rights from winSCP (here's a way to do this http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/1365/how-to-transfer-files-to-server-winscp-gives-permission-denied ) and then get the file. If still you can't get the file, contact the Amazon support. I'm not sure how this cloud computing environment service is working, but there must be a way to get your file.